# Is there an easy way to suppress ResourceWarning when running tests -Wd

Tags: python, django

Is there a way on the Python or Django command line to suppress `ResourceWarning` when running tests with `python -Wd` i.e.

```
python -Wd ./manage.py test ...
```

A bunch of my tests don't close files, which is no problem because the test class instance which opened them goes away and that closes the file. I don't want to spend time editing all the tests. But fishing through the ResourceWarnings for the DeprecationWarnings is rather painful.